# iOS: How to display a banner notification with a dark theme

Tags: ios, swift, unnotificationserviceextension, unnotificationscontentextension

I want to display a banner notification with a dark background and light text. iOS naturally does this if the phone is using dark mode. However, in light mode, when I use WhatsApp, I noticed banners have a dark theme as long as they are displayed while the application is in the foreground.

How can I create something similar? I've been looking into using `UNNotificationContentExtension`. This seems to work for custom actions displayed via a long click. For example, when I set `view.backgroundColor`, this does not set the background color for the whole banner. It only does it for custom actions.

Comment: WhatsApp has probably rolled there own UI workflow - this is evident based on the fact that it only works while the app is in the foreground.  Maybe have a look at "ios toast" for some more ideas

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, since the system manages the creation of these alerts.  This is probably restricted for consistent UI.